Is DCFL a subset of linear languages?
I already know what language hierarchy:
Regular languages are a subset of DCFL which are again a subset of CFL. But not able to understand where does linear language fits in all this.
They are a superset of regular languages and subset of cfl. But how they are related to DCFL?

The Dyck language is a counterexample.

@JeanAbouSamra Dyck language is a dcfl but not a linear language. But this does not tell if linear language is subset of dcfl.

The language $\{a^nb^n \mid n \geqslant 0\} \cup \{a^nb^{2n} \mid n \geqslant 0\}$ is linear but is not deterministic.

So far what I have understood is that there are dcfl languages which are not linear(e.g Dyck language) and there are linear languages which are not dcfl. So neither of them is a subset of the other one. Is this correct?

Yes, the two classes are incomparable.
